# My App crashes whenever it is launched - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

My app crashes whenever I  try to launch it !!
I am trying to run the run on my mobile
The app gets installed but it does not launch
I just made a simple screen with a picture and 2 buttons !!
I tried to change the layout but its still not working!!
can anyone help me please? 
Thank you!!
Here is the Logcat:

```
04-11 21:53:06.636 18950-18950/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-11 21:53:07.256 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
04-11 21:53:07.256 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-11 21:53:07.256 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-11 21:53:07.266 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-11 21:53:07.266 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: Collection enabled
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.myfoodorderapp, 1:235236386201:android:38ab5093f7ffffb9
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myfoodorderapp
04-11 21:53:07.376 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
04-11 21:53:07.426 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-11 21:53:07.476 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
04-11 21:53:07.486 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-11 21:53:07.506 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid pid is 18950
04-11 21:53:07.506 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid value is .myfoodorderapp
04-11 21:53:07.556 18950-18994/com.example.myfoodorderapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-11 21:53:08.016 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-11 21:53:08.026 18950-18950/com.example.myfoodorderapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myfoodorderapp, PID: 18950
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfoodorderapp/com.example.myfoodorderapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.myfoodorderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.myfoodorderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:121)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.myfoodorderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 
04-11 21:53:08.346 18950-18950/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18950 SIG: 9
04-11 21:53:08.346 18950-18950/? V/Process: killProcess [18950] Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:99 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 <bottom of call stack>
```

This is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/as"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"

            />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"

            />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is java file:

```
package com.example.myfoodorderapp;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    TextView txtSlogan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        txtSlogan=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/NABILA.TTF");

        txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `info.hoang8f.widget.FButton`?

Comment: Have you included the FButton library in your gradle file?

Comment: @brandonx yes I did

Comment: @QBrute  it's a widget that I added in the library

Comment: Looking at the source code for that library, that stack trace is saying that you have a `boolean` value for a `shadowHeight` attribute. The posted layout doesn't seem to have that problem, as far as I can see. Try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below from 0 to a higher number

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of a known bug in `info.hoang8f.widget.FButton` library. You can see the issue here: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41.

It is because the FButton class is using an incorrect attribute naming in line [115](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/info/hoang8f/widget/FButton.java#L115):

```
else if (attr == R.styleable.FButton_buttonColor) {
  ...
}
```

this problem has been corrected in another fork: https://gitlab.com/RilixTechnology/android-flat-button or https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button

Comment: You might have another read through the stack trace. The Exception is thrown on line 121, by a call to `TypedArray#getDimensionPixelSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

problem in you xml file where you used

```
 <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"

       />
```

this Widget can't inflate, try to fix it or Remove.